# Cannot find previous revision of projects when applying version settings in teamcity

Tags: kotlin, teamcity

using kotlin script,able to build the kotlin project but when trying to apply the latest changes in teamcity,
Cannot find previous revision of projects: [ProjectA, ProjectB], skip updating settings to revision 59a2f22ce00bdd97002d3f8c6961d619ffe925dc

Both ProjectA and ProjectB build configurations has been modified and new projects projectsC and projectsD are in place.

Answer (score 1):

What TeamCity version do you use? There is [a similar bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-60850) and it's fixed in 2019.1.1 version.

Do you use portable DSL? If not then if you changed `uuid` you can see the similar problems (as TeamCity thinks that you removed projects and this is not allowed with DSL).

BTW, how did you added new projects B and D? What else did you change in projects A and B besides adding new build configurations?

Comment: I was using 2019.1.2 EAP. But issue was resolved when i reset the,Synchronization flag to disabled and then re-enabling the synchronization flag corrected the issue.
Issue occurs only intermittently when i have added a set of projects through the kotlin script and i modify those projects. Projects A and B were removed to add new subprojects C and D

Comment: @JoePauly It's 2022, latest TC Cloud and this is still the only solution that works.

Comment: @EitelDagnin  Thanks for pointing the year,rather than solution.

Comment: I'm reaffirming that this is indeed the only "solution" with latest release. No need to be so salty.